# Receiver '**' for class message is a forward declaration Error. Swift Static Library use in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make a Swift Static library and apply it to Swift and Objective Project.

```
import Foundation

@objc open class Library001_Test: NSObject {
   public override init(){}

   @objc public func testPrint() {
      print("My Name is Andi")
   }

   @objc public func getUUID(userName: String) -> String {
      let uuid = UUID().uuidString
      return "\(userName)'s UUID : \(uuid)"
   }
}
```

I wrote the code like this using Swift.

[image]

And in the Edit Scheme menu, I changed the Build Configuration to Release and proceeded with Run. As a result, the 'libLibrary001.a' file and the 'Library001.swiftmodule' folder were created.

[image]
These two artifacts work well when pasted into a Swift project and imported.

But the problem is an Objective-C project.

[image]

I put both artifacts into my project and checked:

1. [General - Frameworks, Libraries. and Embedded Content] whether the library is recognized
2. Whether the library is recognized in [Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries]
3. Check [Build Settings - Library Search Paths] address
4. Defines Module - Yes

And I put '@class Library001_Test;' in ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Library001_Test;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

And in ViewController.m, '#import "ProductName-Swift.h" and the created Class were loaded.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SwiftInObjectiveC-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    Library001_Test *test = [[Library001_Test alloc] init];
}
@end
```

[image]

**error : Receiver 'Library001_Test' for class message is a forward declaration**

**error : Receiver type 'Library001_Test' for instance message is a forward declaration**

An error occurred while doing this. I've tried all the methods I've found on the internet and I'm wondering where the problem is.

Is the code the problem? Did I not set it up well??

The Swift file created in the project is import well in Objective-C... Why the hell is the .a file not working like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was with '(ProductName)-Swift.h'

If you look at how Swift Code is used in Objective-C, many articles say to import (ProductName)-Swift.h. So I only added the project header that I want to apply, but I also need to add the product header made from the library.

My problem was simple, but it took me a long time to figure it out. The error was not found 'Class' and 'func' in Swift static library. My workaround was resolved using the (LibraryProductName)-Swift.h of the library I created, rather than the (ProductName)-Swift.h of the project you are working on.

If you refer to the address below, you can prevent the error that occurred in advance.

https://medium.com/@mail2ashislaha/swift-objective-c-interoperability-static-libraries-modulemap-etc-39caa77ce1fc